# Make dropdown option take you to external link?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown with the options taking you to external sites or in my case my website but another language.

I have already made the dropdown but I don't know where to put the code which will allow you to go to the site.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('active')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="btn">Change Language</button>
  <a href="https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=709030261605793803&permissions=171166800&scope=bot">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Invite To Discord</button>
    <a href="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Get Started</button>
      <ul class="active">
        <li><a href="#">Français</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Português</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">русский (Russian)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to translate your page ?

Comment: Yes but i am just trying to make the dropdown work as intended. Because the main index.html page is in english and i want people to be able to choose options for languages. **I hope that made sense.**

Comment: Replace `#` with the actual URLs?

Comment: Im so stupid. I thought they were just a placeholder. Thanks

Comment: You can't put links or buttons inside links...and vice versa, it's invalid HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `#` within your `<a>` tags with the actual urls of the page you want to direct to. Also, your html doesn't seem correct. Links within links, plus the addition of buttons all seems very confusing. Depending on what you are trying to do, try simplifying it to something like this...

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="francais.html">Français</a></li>
    <li><a href="portugues.htm">Português</a></li>
    <li><a href="russian.html">русский (Russian)</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```